# ASP.Net MVC - Won't recognize 'this HtmlHelper'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to implement a custom HtmlHelper for a custom Date format.
(Because `TextBoxFor` ignores the date format attribute and `EditorFor` ignores classes, but that's not the problem)
Here's the custom HtmlHelper :

```
namespace SigmaAdminCore.MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static class MyHtmlHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MyDateFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            var mvcHtmlString = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression, new { @class = "text-box single-line date-picker" });
            var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(mvcHtmlString.ToHtmlString());
            var xElement = xDoc.Element("input");
            if (xElement != null)
            {
                var valueAttribute = xElement.Attribute("value");
                if (valueAttribute != null)
                {
                    valueAttribute.Value = DateTime.Parse(valueAttribute.Value).ToShortDateString();
                    if (valueAttribute.Value == "1/1/0001")
                        valueAttribute.Value = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            return new MvcHtmlString(xDoc.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And in my view I have :

```
@using SigmaAdminCore.MyHtmlHelpers
...
@MyHtmlHelpers.MyDateFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)
```

And here's the error :

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'expression' of 'MyHtmlHelpers.MyDateFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>)'

My guess is that ASP doesn't replace `this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper` by the proper value or don't know how to. Even though `MyDateFor` method has the same signature as `TextBoxFor` method defined in InputExtensions.cs :

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

Comment: Its just `@Html.MyDateFor()` (not `@MyHtmlHelpers.MyDateFor()`)

Comment: You might also want to consider adding `<add namespace="SigmaAdminCore.MyHtmlHelpers" />` to you `web.config` file so you don't need the `using` statement in the view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
@MyHtmlHelpers.MyDateFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)
```

Should be:

```
@Html.MyDateFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)
```

As you've extended `this HtmlHelper<TModel>`.

---

Basically the line `this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper` makes it an extension method of `HtmlHelper<TModel>`.
"Under the hood" the type of a cshtml file is `WebViewPage<TModel>` and that has this line on it:

```
public HtmlHelper<TModel> Html { get; set; }
```

Which makes your extension method available by `@html`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you explain how my class extended HtmlHelper without explicitly specifying it ? Also, I thought `MyDateFor` method was only accessible from the class I created, how is it possible to be accessible from `@Html.` ?

Answer (score 1):

It must be `@Html.MyDateFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)` instead of `@MyHtmlHelpers.MyDateFor(model => model.ExpirationDate)`